# Mnemonics for typical integrations

Tags: integration, soft-question, indefinite-integrals, mnemonic

I am supposed to mug up these integrals for my upcoming exams:

$$\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\sin^{-1}\frac xa+C$$
$$\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}|+C$$
$$\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-\frac{a^2}{2}\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}|+C$$

I have been trying all my past one year trying to mug them up, ever since this chapter of indefinite integration was introduced, yet I keep messing the terms/$\pm$ signs/etc. every single time.

I hope there could be a few mnemonics to help learn these integrals. I am not necessarily looking for a song or an animated gif, but perhaps, any thing that the mind can instantly hook up to, and connect to these equations, is appreciated.

Comment: Clarification: I understand that rote learning these integrals might be pointless for many people, since these are not as popular integrals as that of $\tan x$ or $\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}$, but still, they are very useful to a large community of students preparing for some extrance exams here. Hence, my question.

Comment: I feel you bro...

Comment: @JaideepKhare Yes... I really wish I had asked this question a little early last year, instead of hopelessly trying to rote learn them, which I eventually couldn't anyway :(

Comment: Well there are many more to learn. for example integral of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$

Comment: @JaideepKhare It (and the bunch of other "denominator" type of integrals), imho, pales in comparison to the three integrals I posted above ^_^ Once you learn those three, the rest feel trivially easy :D

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to memorize one _method of solving_ these types of integrals instead of memorizing these three? The method is quite short and simple. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2627812/464998

Comment: @bames Thanks for the suggestion! The method you linked to is reasonably short and easy to derive within a minute. With practice I think I can perfect it. I'll use it for the time being, and leave this question open, till someone comes up with a proper mnemonic, which would lead to the final result more directly.

Answer (score 1):

As bames [suggested above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636865/mnemonics-for-typical-integrations#comment5445389_2636865), the *method of solving* for these indefinite integrations is actually a helpful tool in quickly recalling them. Here, I will provide a simple derivation - for the three integrations I listed - that helped me recall them within thirty seconds on paper. This is a long post, because it captures the exact method that I currently use.

---

#### $\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\sin^{-1}\frac xa+C$

$$\begin{align}
I=\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}~dx
&=\int\frac{a^2-x^2}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx\\
&=\int\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx-\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx\\
&=a^2\sin^{-1}\frac xa-\int x\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx
\end{align}$$

Now, apply the Integration-By-Parts rule on the second integrand as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\int x\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx
&=x\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}-\int\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx\\
&=-x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx\\
&=-x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+I
\end{align}$$

Substituting it back, we get:

$$\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\sin^{-1}\frac xa+C$$

---

### $\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}~dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}|+C$

$$
\begin{align}
I=\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}~dx
&=\int\frac{x^2+a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx\\
&=\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx+\int\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx\\
&=\int x\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx+a^2\ln|\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x|+C'
\end{align}
$$

Now, apply the Integration-By-Parts rule on the first integrand as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\int x\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx&=x\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx-\int\int \frac x{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx\\
&=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\\
&=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-I
\end{align}$$

Substituting it back, we get: $$I=\frac x2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+\frac{a^2}2\ln|\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x|+C$$

---

### $\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2}~dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-\frac{a^2}{2}\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}|+C$

$$
\begin{align}
I=\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2}~dx
&=\int\frac{x^2-a^2}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx\\
&=\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx-\int\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx\\
&=\int x\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx-a^2\ln|\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+x|+C'
\end{align}
$$

Now, apply the Integration-By-Parts rule on the first integrand as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\int x\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx
&=x\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx-\int\int \frac x{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx\\
&=x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\\
&=x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-I
\end{align}$$

Substituting it back, we get: $$I=\frac x2\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-\frac{a^2}2\ln|\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+x|+C$$

---

**Quick references:**

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx&=\frac 1{a}\int\frac{a\sec^2\theta}{\sqrt{\tan^2\theta+1}}d\theta ~~(\because x=a\tan\theta)\\
&=\int\sec\theta d\theta\\
&=\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C'\\
&=\ln|\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x|+C
\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx&=\frac 1{a}\int\frac{a\sec\theta\tan\theta}{\sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1}}d\theta ~~(\because x=a\sec\theta)\\
&=\int\sec\theta d\theta\\
&=\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C'\\
&=\ln|\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+x|+C
\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx&=
\frac 1{a}\int\frac{a\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}d\theta ~~(\because x=a\sin\theta)\\
&=\int d\theta\\
&=\theta+C'\\
&=\sin^{-1}\frac xa+C
\end{align}$$